# Triggering an alert if the element that is clicked matches the array item in my random function

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, onclick

I am making a flexbox grid game. Each square has its own id. 
The point of the game is that the computer will think of a random square(this is a randomized array function where each square id is an array element), and if you clicked the same one the computer thought of, an alert message pops up telling you you picked the right one. Otherwise it tells you its wrong.

I cant figure out how to link the clicked item into the if else statement so i can check to see if it matches up with the random number. This is what I have so far.

```
<body onload ="pickNumber()">
    <div class="container"">
        <button id="flex1" onclick="showAnswer()"></button>
        <button id="flex2" onclick="showAnswer()"></button>
        ...and so on and so forth
    </div>
</body>

function pickNumber() {
    var grid = ["flex1", "flex2", "flex3", "flex4", "flex5", "flex6", "flex7", "flex8", "flex9"];
    var randomNumber = grid[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

function showAnswer() {
     if (id.target == randomNumber) {
     alert("Correct!");
     } else {
     alert("Sorry, try again!");
     }
}
```

Comment: what is `values & id` here?? and remove one " from `class="container""`

Answer (score 0):

The functionality should be something like the below and you can work out the formatting. The problems with your code were:

1. When you set a variable within a function (like you set `randomNumber`), then it is not accessible outside that function. Therefore, declare the variable outside the function first and then manipulate with the function
2. randomNumber was returning a number starting from 0, but your id's start from 1
3. `id.target == randomNumber` - it should be `target.id`, with `target` passed on within the function - otherwise `target` is not declared anywhere

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for( let i=0, lenn = boxes.length; i < lenn; i ++ ){
  boxes[i].onclick = function() {
    var comp_guess = pickNumber();
    if( boxes[i].id == comp_guess ) {
          alert('You win! You guessed '+boxes[i].id);
    } else {
          alert('No candy.');
      }
  }
}
function pickNumber() {
    var grid = ["flex1", "flex2", "flex3", "flex4", "flex5", "flex6", "flex7", "flex8", "flex9"];
    return grid[Math.floor(Math.random() * grid.length)];
}
```

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:2em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex1"></div>
<div id="flex2"></div>
<div id="flex3"></div>
<div id="flex4"></div>
<div id="flex5"></div>
<div id="flex6"></div>
<div id="flex7"></div>
<div id="flex8"></div>
<div id="flex9"></div>
```

Comment: No worries! If it resolved your query you can accept it as the correct answer and upvote it to stick it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

In you code `grid` and `randomNumber` are local variables to the function `pickNumber()` so you can't expect them to work as same variables in `showAnswer()`.

In `showAnswer()` where is the `id` defined. You'll have to pass a event argument to the function and then get the id by `e.target.id`. I would suggest if that's the only purpose of the id here then you should use [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

Also going by naming convention `randomNumber` should be a number but instead is a element of the `grid` so changed that in my code bellow have a look.

```js
var grid = ["flex1", "flex2", "flex3", "flex4", "flex5", "flex6", "flex7"];
var randomNumber;

(function newRandNum() {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid.length);
})();

var flexBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-btn");

for(var i=0; i<flexBtns.length; i++){
  flexBtns[i].onclick = flexBtnClick;
}
console.log("Correct box is " + Number(randomNumber+1));

function flexBtnClick(e) {
  if(e.target.id == grid[randomNumber]){
    console.log("Correct!");
    newRandNum();
  }else{
    console.log("Sorry, try again!");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="flex1" class="flex-btn">flex1</button>
    <button id="flex2" class="flex-btn">flex2</button>
    <button id="flex3" class="flex-btn">flex3</button>
    <button id="flex4" class="flex-btn">flex4</button>
    <button id="flex5" class="flex-btn">flex5</button>
    <button id="flex6" class="flex-btn">flex6</button>
    <button id="flex7" class="flex-btn">flex7</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this didn't produce a randomized answer. The right answer kept being the same every time.

Comment: @suzyc everytime I run the code snippet I get a new number so what you are talking about?

Comment: Modified the code a bit. Now every time you get the correct guess the new random number will be assigned no need to run the code again.